# Sorting of data in descending order

Tags: linux, string, sorting

Allow me to clarify my query:

I have a database with thousand of character strings, followed by some values (based on scoring matrix)

```
    GKCHGYEGRGFQGRHYEGRSDGPNGQL  25
    WGCGGYESRGFQGRHYEGGGDCPNGQG  56
    GLCCGYEGRGFQCRHYEGGGDGPNDQL  43
    GKGCGYEGRGFQGRHYEHGIDKDHFFR  24
    PYGSGGNRARRSGCSWMLYEQVNYSGD   4
    DFTEDLRCLQDVFAFNEIVSLNVLERL   3
    REDYRRQSIYELSNYRCRQYLTDPSDY  18
```

There are equal values also present. I am trying to sort the data in descending order using:

```
    sort -n -r file.txt
```

But the data is still disarranged. Also tried by adding -k argument.

Is it possible that i could get the following result:

```
   GKCHGYEGRGFQGRHYEGRSDGPNGQL  56
   WGCGGYESRGFQGRHYEGGGDCPNGQG  56
   GLCCGYEGRGFQCRHYEGGGDGPNDQL  56
   GKGCGYEGRGFQGRHYEHGIDKDHFFR  43
   PYGSGGNRARRSGCSWMLYEQVNYSGD  25
   DFTEDLRCLQDVFAFNEIVSLNVLERL  25
   REDYRRQSIYELSNYRCRQYLTDPSDY  24
```

and so on.

I am new to Linux. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `sort -k 2 -nr` should work

Comment: Yayy :) thank you so much ...its working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sort -k 2 -nr
```

This will number sort 2nd field in reverse order and print